# reCaptcha appears on mobile device but not on desktop/laptop

Tags: javascript, angularjs, recaptcha

I have come through a weird issue. Normally it's the other way around.
My recaptcha appears on mobile device browser but does not appear in any browsers on my computer.

Below is my code.
I'm using angular-recaptcha for my site.

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div vc-recaptcha ng-model="registration.recaptcha" key="'therecaptchapublickey'"></div>
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Below is my angular code.
var app = angular.module('myapp',['ui.toggle','vcRecaptcha']);

```
app.controller('checkoutCtrl', function($scope, $http, $timeout){
   if($scope.registration.recaptcha != null || $scope.registration.recaptcha != undefined){
                $scope.emailmatch = 1;
                console.log('recaptcha ok');
            } else {
                $scope.emailmatch = 0;
                console.log('recaptcha invalid');
            }
});
```

I do not get any errors on the console or anything. The recaptcha is simply not displayed in any of the browsers. Clearing cache didn't help at all. But the captcha is displayed on mobile devices.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you using a real domain? Key is valid?

Comment: Are your desktop and mobile connecting on the same network?

Comment: yes I am using a real domain and key is accurate. Now it seems that the captcha is working only for Android stock browser. Chrome on android isn't working either. This code was working fine before. Just out of the blue it decided to stop working. Any idea guys?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that this happens because I am loading the recaptcha.js from google as well as the angular-recaptcha.js file. Seems like the angular-recaptcha.js loads the recaptcha so removing the google recaptcha.js did the trick.